# converting the table and insert in other table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table:

```
-----------------------
Name |  Age |  Gender |
-----------------------
abc  |  22  |  m      |
pqr  |  26  |  m      |
xyz  |  33  |  f      |  
-----------------------
```

and I want to insert it into another table:

```
Value    Variable

name     abc
age      22
gender   m
name     pqr
age      26
gender   m
name     xyz
age      33
gender   f
```

How can I do this in PL/SQL?
How can I do this if my table contains millions of records?

Comment: Your question tells that you don't know anything in PLSQL. So it is better to refer a book or PLSQL teaching site in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into other_table (value, variables)
select 'name', name from your_table
union all
select 'age', age from your_table
union all
select 'gender', gender from your_table
```

Comment: i want to insert first table values into second table like that way.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PL/SQL for this. Just:

```
insert all
    into other_table (thing_name, thing_value) values ('name',   name)
    into other_table (thing_name, thing_value) values ('age',    age)
    into other_table (thing_name, thing_value) values ('gender', gender)
select name, age, gender from some_table;
```